# Force branch to become master

Tags: git, github, git-merge, github-desktop

I have branch `Dev` which is everything I need. My `master` branch is down bad right now and I just want to completely put the dev branch onto master. I don't need anything on the master branch, just want dev copied onto master.

ive tried:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard dev
git push -f origin master
```

but it wants me to resolve conflicts, which isn't working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing you can do, and that is to change the refs. So, if you are SURE that you do not need anything on the master branch, try this:

1. Delete the master branch, both locally and on the remote repository.
2. Just rename the "Dev" branch  to "master" with this command
   "git branch -m Dev master"
3. Push any changes to the master branch (previously "Dev") upstream.